# How to do Join with these conditions in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table (A):

```
ID  PROD PER
1   45  1
2   21  2
3   45  3
4   223 12
5 543 6
```

And table B:

```
ID  CAS DATE
1   ttt 062017
2   ddd 062017
3   fff 062017
4   fre 062017
5 grs 062017
```

Conditions:

```
PER = 1 and DATE between 01%%%% and 12%%%%
PER = 2 and DATE=02%%%% OR DATE=04%%%% OR DATE=06%%%% OR DATE=08%%%% OR DATE=10%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%
PER = 3 and DATE=03%%%% OR DATE=06%%%% OR DATE=09%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%
PER = 4 and DATE=04%%%% OR DATE=08%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%
PER = 6 and DATE=06%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%
PER = 12 and DATE=12%%%%
```

I want to do join A and B:

```
select * from A
join B
on A.ID=B.ID
CONDITIONS
```

The expected result:

```
ID  PROD CAS PER DATE
1   45  ttt 1 062017
2   21  ddd 2 062017
3   45  fff 3 062017
5 543 grs 6 062017
```

I hope I have explained correctly. In short, what I am looking for is a join between the tables with the exposed conditions.

Comment: `where (per = 1 and ...) or (per = 2 and ...) or ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(for mysql):

```
select a.*, b.cas, b.`date`
from tablea a
join tableb b
on a.id = b.id
and mod(left(b.`date`, 2) + 0, a.per) = 0
```

[***Demo***](http://rextester.com/CQZLXZ41311) in rextester.

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Some product specific features used, and the question has no dbms specified.)

Comment: Hello Forward, 
What you have proposed does not work when the date is 6

Comment: Are you using mysql? Or show more sample data and your expected result. @Anna_MS

Comment: @Anna_MS Even your new sample data, it also works, please check this [demo](http://rextester.com/JSU16554).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM A
JOIN B ON 
     A.ID = B.ID
WHERE
(PER = 1 and (DATE between 01%%%% OR 12%%%%)) OR
(PER = 2 and (DATE=02%%%% OR DATE=04%%%% OR DATE=06%%%% OR DATE=08%%%% OR DATE=10%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%)) OR
(PER = 3 and (DATE=03%%%% OR DATE=06%%%% OR DATE=09%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%)) OR
(PER = 4 and (DATE=04%%%% OR DATE=08%%%% OR DATE=12%%%%)) OR
(PER = 12 and DATE=12%%%%)
```

For more details you can visit: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
select A.ID,A.PROD,D.CAS,A.PER,B.DATE from A
join B
on A.ID=B.ID
WHERE 
(A.PER = 1 and B.DATE between 01%%%% and 12%%%%) AND
(A.PER = 2 and B.DATE=02%%%% OR B.DATE=04%%%% OR B.DATE=06%%%% OR B.DATE=08%%%% OR B.DATE=10%%%% OR B.DATE=12%%%%) AND
(A.PER = 3 and B.DATE=03%%%% OR B.DATE=06%%%% OR B.DATE=09%%%% OR B.DATE=12%%%%) AND
(A.PER = 4 and B.DATE=04%%%% OR B.DATE=08%%%% OR B.DATE=12%%%%) OR
(A.PER = 12 and B.DATE=12%%%%)
```

Let me know in case of any issues

Comment: Please modify the dates where ever required

Comment: You forgot to join conditions

Comment: Which join ? Please elobrate

Answer (score 0):

You  should be making use of the `LIKE` keyword for comparison. See below :

```
SELECT          tab1.id, 
                tab1.PROD, 
                tab2.CAS, 
                tab2.Datum
FROM            Table1 tab1
INNER JOIN      Table2 tab2 ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
WHERE           (tab1.PER = 1 AND tab2.DATUM BETWEEN '01%' AND '12%')
OR              (tab1.PER = 2 AND (tab2.DATUM LIKE '02%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '04%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '06%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '08%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '10%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '12%'))
OR              (tab1.PER = 3 AND (tab2.DATUM LIKE '03%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '06%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '09%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '12%'))
OR              (tab1.PER = 4 AND (tab2.DATUM LIKE '04%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '08%' OR tab2.DATUM LIKE '12%'))
OR              (tab1.PER = 12 AND tab2.DATUM = '12%')
```

This is a simple solution and should work in all the major DBMS's.

You can see this working here -> http://rextester.com/MYBHC51508

Hope this helps!!!